# Send activation link to user after registration in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am using custom user registration and log in in **WordPress**. Now I want to send a mail containing activation link to the registered user so that they can complete their registration after clicking that link.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it something like by adding this code in  `fucntions.php` your `send_activation_link()` functon in 
`add_action ( 'user_register', 'send_activation_link');`

`user_register` is a hook, which runs at the end of user creation

```
function send_activation_link(){
$hash = md5( $random_number );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'hash', $hash );
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$to = $user_info->user_email;           
$subject = 'Member Verification'; 
$message = 'Hello,';
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Welcome...';
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Username: '.$un;
$message .= "\n";
$message .= 'Password: '.$pw;
$message .= "\n\n";
$message .= 'Please click this link to activate your account:';
$message .= home_url('/').'activate?id='.$un.'&key='.$hash;
$headers = 'From: noreply@test.com' . "\r\n";           
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

Its not a complete answer but just to give an idea to work something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use "User Activation E-mail" Wordpress plugin to do that.

Here is the link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-activation-email/

[image: How user can activate account]

I hope this will help you!